# cannot create a new action in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Try to add a new action in TasksController.php as

```
public function magic(){
   debug("hi");
   exit;
}
```

Then load the page http://example.com/tasks/magic, but it redirects to http://example.com.

I checked router.php already, and no "magic" is defined anyway. And I also changed the action name to 'magical', "myaction", etc, but no luck, they're all being redirected to the homepage.

Any idea?

Comment: Look in DebugKit under "Request" -> Current Route to see what route it's using.  If it's as expected, just `echo "something"; exit;` starting in your AppController's beforeFilter() and see how far you get to find out where the issue is happening.

Comment: Do you have ACL in place, and if so, did you give access to your new action?

Comment: Thanks Nunser! It must be that. I need to regenerate ACL I guess.

Comment: Nunser, how can I accept your answer since you posted it in the comment? Thanks!

Comment: I'll post an answer with the solution since it might help someone else, just give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common things that cause this "problem":

1. Using `private` or `protected` visibility on actions. All actions that can be accessed by url should be `public`.
2. Falling into a "routing hell". You need to check that the action is using the intended route. Like Dave said, you could check this with DebugKit, under Request.
3. You are validating something, it doesn't pass validation and redirects you somewhere else (but you absolutely swear the id is set (so really really check first))

   ```
   public function index($id=null) {
      if (!$this->Model->exists($id))
         $this->redirect(/*somewhere*/);
   ```
4. You are using some kind of ACL and the permission tree (or whatever it is) wasn't updated after adding a new action. If you made your function `private` and then change it to `public` without updating, it will also give you this error.

Those are the common issues that cause this problem with actions.

Apparently the problem here was the ACL, but as a rule of thumb, always check all numbered possible scenarios before giving into panic and run around in circles because it didn't work :) Any error that doesn't fall into these scenarios probably merit a new google search and a new question (if other questions/answers don't help).